# Git nested submodule fails to clone

Tags: git, nested, git-submodules

I have a repository (A) that uses another repository (B) as a submodule. Now I want to include repository A in a third repository (C) as a submodule, but when I try to clone it, the nested submodule B is not cloned with submodule A.

Things I tried:

- git clone --recursive *url-to-repository-C*
- git submodule update --init --recursive
- git submodule sync --recursive && git submodule update --init --recursive

All of them give me the same error:
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'local-path-to-where-repository-B-should-clone-into' in .gitmodules

I had a look at the .gitmodules file in the root folder of repository C and I have an entry for submodule A. And in the folder for B I have a second .gitmodules with an entry for submodule B.

Is there something I have to configure in repos A, B, or C for this to work?

(Adding an entry for submodule B in the .gitmodules for repository C directly is not an option. I am currently trying to get my coworkers to adopt git instead of svn and repository A is the backbone framework of our projects. If they need to jump through hoops for this repository to clone correctly, my endevour is doomed.)

Edit: I noticed that the entry for submodule B in repository A is different when I check it out A directly instead of as a submodule.

Comment: did you try `git submodule add <url of A>`?

Comment: that is how I added A as a submodule to C